# Rust Analyzer doesn't create warning for undefined variables

Tags: rust, rust-analyzer

For some reason Rust Analyzer isn't generating a warning for undefined variables. Do I need to tweak some settings somewhere?

[image]

I'm also not getting warnings for unused variables, unimported crates, etc.

Edit: Tested this out with a new workspace. Both `cargo check` and Rust Analyzer work. It reports a single intentional error. When I run `cargo check` in the first workspace, it reports a lot of errors in the `~/.cargo` directory, and none in the current workspace. Perhaps a crate I am using has errors and is locking up `cargo check` before it can get around to checking the files in my directory?

Comment: I can't replicate, can you give more detail?

Comment: @JaredSmith Not sure - I'm using a monorepo with a Cargo.toml in the root directory which contains `[workspace]` followed by `members = ["apps/project1", "apps/project2", "packages/crate1", etc. ]`.

Comment: Does `cargo check` show the error?

Comment: What version of rust-analyzer with which text editor?

Comment: @PitaJ doesn't appear to- it only appears to be running on the `~/.cargo` directory. I don't want to be creating a red herring with that last part though

Comment: @JaredSmith v0.3.1301 with VSCode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The log when running `cargo check` showed some issues with `~/.cargo/registry/src/github.com-xx..xx/rppal-0.12.0`. This came from a the crate `rust_gpiozero` that I had listed as a dependency. As best as I can figure, `cargo check` was failing on this and then ceasing to analyze my files. After removing this dependency, both `cargo check` and Rust Analyzer run as expected.

Cheers to all who replied to this thread for their guidance.

Answer (score 4):

For another possible cause: try `cargo clean`.

This problem happened to me after upgrading my toolchain version. As mentioned in other answers, running `cargo check` yielded many errors. The topmost error mentioned a crate "compiled by an incompatible version of rustc." Running `cargo clean` followed by `cargo check` fixed all errors.

Answer (score 0):

Rust-analyzer itself doesn't produce errors or warnings for this.

If you want warnings and errors, enable the "Check on Enable" option in the rust-analyzer extension. This will run `cargo check` every time you save a Rust file and display the emitted warnings and errors in the files.

Comment: Enable "check on save" perhaps? This has already been enabled, and I get a handful of warnings for things like incomplete statements (ex. `let x = ` throws an error.), however I don't get any errors for the more complex things. Between your and @PitaJ's responses, it seems like this is perhaps a cargo error rather than a Rust Analyzer error.